# how to fix function getClientOriginalExtension() on null on laravel

Tags: laravel

check out the code that i am getting error on **"Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on bool"**

i used image intervention properties on laravel to upload image on product table . while usng **getClientOriginalExtension()** i got error...

```
public function product_store(Request $request)
{

    $image = $request->hasfile('product_image');
    $img = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('images/products/' .$img);
    Image::make($imge)->save($location);

    $product_image = new productImage;
    $product_image->product_id = 1;
    $product_image->image = $img;
    $product_image->save();

    return redirect() -> route('admin.product.create');
}
```

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on bool

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; `$image` is a `boolean`, and `getClientOriginalExtension()` can't be called on a `boolean`

Answer (score 5):

`hasFile` returning boolean.Try this -

```
$image = $request->file('product_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasFile()` to check if there is a file or not!

```
if ($request->hasFile('product_image')) {
    $image = $request->file('product_image');
}
```

then get the extension using :

```
$imageExt = $image->extension();
```